# Почему не сохраняются/удаляются пробелы в EntityFramework?

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

Имеется EF6 Code-First. При сохранении сущности Property удаляются пробелы в конце и/или начале значения свойства Name. Проблема заключается в том, что мне необходимо сохранять эти пробелы, т.к. такое поведение не даёт возможности сохранять сущности различающиеся своим написанием. Предвидя критику, что сохранение таких данных - это ошибка, поясню, что программа предназначена именно для анализа и сбора таких данных.

Каким образом можно изменить поведение EntityFramework и позволить сохранять пробельные символы в конце и/или начале значения свойства?

```
public partial class MyContext : DbContext {
    public MyContext() : base("name=MyContext") { }
    // ...
    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder) {

        modelBuilder.Entity<Property>()
            .Property(e => e.Group)
            .IsFixedLength();
        modelBuilder.Entity<Property>()
            .Property(e => e.Name)
            .IsFixedLength();
    }
}

public partial class Property {

    public SEProperty() {}

    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Group { get; set; }

    [StringLength(255)]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Скрипт создания таблицы выглядит следующим образом:

```sql
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Property](
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Group] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [Name] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_dbo.Property] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (
    [Id] ASC
) WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, 
        STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, 
        IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, 
        ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, 
        ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

Comment: Что-то вы не договариваете. При подходе Code-First из показазанных классов никак не мог получиться такой SQL.

Comment: Если убрать `IsFixedLength()`, то колонки создаются типа `nvarchar`. Пробелы при этом сохраняются и никуда не деваются. Какой у вас тип проекта - ASP.NET? Могу предположить, что данные из БД выводятся в html. Соответственно, пробельные символы обрезаются браузером.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov Я убрал несущественные детали. На данный момент выглядит так, что проблема не в EF, а в SQL сервере. Он возвращает неправильную запись. То есть, при запросе `select * from [Property] where [Name] = 'abc   '`, завершающие пробелы игнорируются и возвращается запись с `'abc'`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Проблема заключалась не в EF, а в MS SQL сервере, который возвращал строку без завершающих пробелов, т.е. игнорировал завершающие пробелы при сравнении строк, что в свою очередь приводило к дальнейшим ошибкам. Другими словами, для сервера строки `'abc'` и `'abc  '` эквивалентны.
[Здесь](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/316626/inf-how-sql-server-compares-strings-with-trailing-spaces) разъясняется как MS SQL сервер сравнивает строки с пробелами.

Проблему решил костылём - "оборачиванием" значений в предопределенный символ, например `'-abc  -'`. Таким образом пробелы больше не могут являться первыми или последними символами.

Помимо вышеуказанного, проблема возникает при использовании `IsFixedLength()`. Ниже приведены некоторые примеры преобразования в SQL из которых следует, что для корректной фильтрации не следует использовать фиксированную длинну:

```
var prop = db.Properties.FirstOrDefault(e => e.Name.EndsWith("term"));
// SQL: where [Name] LIKE '%term'
var prop = db.Properties.FirstOrDefault(e => e.Name.StartsWith("term"));
// SQL: where [Name] LIKE 'term%'
var prop = db.Properties.FirstOrDefault(e => e.Name.Contains("term"));
// SQL: where [Name] LIKE '%term%'
```

Comment: Ну что ж, хорошо, что всё прояснилось. Так-то да, ansi_padding имеет место быть.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov Не уверен, что корректно понял, что Вы имели ввиду. По ссылке приведенной выше утверждается, что:
The SET ANSI_PADDING setting does not affect whether SQL Server pads strings before it compares them. SET ANSI_PADDING only affects whether trailing blanks are trimmed from values being inserted into a table, so **it affects storage but not comparisons**. 
Или я в не том направлении смотрю?

Answer (score 1):

Тип данных поменяй с nvarhcar to nchar нужной длины.

Comment: Если я правильно понимаю, то в таком случае оставшееся место будет заполняться пробелами, что не даст возможности сохранить значения различающиеся количеством пробелов в конце и/или начале значения.